# Asp Net MVC что используют для написания клиентского приложения?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

как я понял, серверная часть и веб приложение пишется на MVC. а если я хочу написать клиентское приложение которое взаимодействует с сервером на MVC, что использовать для его написания ? (клиентского прил.)

Comment: Если вы планируете писать несколько клтентов для одного сервера (например, web, мобильный, настольный клиенты), то я бы глядел в сторону Web.API, чтобы один и тот же API мог быть использован разными клиентами.

Comment: некоторое время назад появился Blazor, релизная версия вроде как выйдет этой осенью, но уже несколько преоктов пробовал писать - все просто отлично(если не считать проблем в preview версиях, которые, к счастью, быстро фиксятся).